# How To align the input box as center inside the each column of the table

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I am trying to center the input box inside the column of the table but not working . I am looking for a solution. I have given the column width size in style of the html

```html
<style>
   
    .columnwidth{
        width:5em;
    }
    .datewidth {
        width: 8em;
    }
</style>


<table id="attendance" class="table cell-border" style="width:100%">
  <thead class="thead-light">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;width:5em">Sunday<br />NetHrs</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;width:5em">Monday<br />NetHrs</td>
   <td style="text-align:center;width:5em">Tuesday<br />NetHrs</td>
   <td style="text-align:center;width:5em">Wednesday<br />NetHrs</td>
   <td style="text-align:center;width:5em">Thursday<br />NetHrs</td>
   <td style="text-align:center;width:5em">Friday<br />NetHrs</td>
   <td style="text-align:center;width:5em">Saturday<br />NetHrs</td>
 </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
                                              
 <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SundayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "text", @class = "form-control empHrs columnwidth format-text" } })</td>
<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MondayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "text", @class = "form-control empHrs columnwidth  format-text" } })</td>
<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TuesdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "text", @class = "form-control  columnwidth empHrs" } })</td>
<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WednesdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "text", @class = "form-control columnwidth  empHrs" } })</td>
<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ThursdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "text", @class = "form-control columnwidth  empHrs" } })</td>
<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FridayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "text", @class = "form-control columnwidth  empHrs" } })</td>
<td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SaturdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "text", @class = "form-control columnwidth  empHrs" } })</td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: First of all it should not work, because the code is not valid. You're missing closing " in the lines 2,3,4

@class = "form-control    }

Comment: Check out [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and you will see a lot of options of how to control the display of your content much more efficiently.

Comment: I have corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is your `empHrs` css class. Except for `empHrs`, `form-control` class contains `dispaly:block` which influences the style:

[image]

You need add the following css style like below:

```
<style>
    //...
    input {
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
</style>
```

Result:
[image]